# addition operation in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing a simple program in Excel VBA. I have created a simple UserForm for arithmetic operations. I have created two input text boxes and 4 command boxes for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. When I run the code I am able to do all operations except addition operation. When I enter  the two inputs and click on addition command button, the result is getting concatenated instead of doing the addition operation. Eg: Input 1 = 10 , Input 2 = 10. Result= 1010.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

ANSWER = INPUT1 * INPUT2

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

ANSWER = INPUT1 - INPUT2

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

ANSWER = INPUT1 + INPUT2

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

ANSWER = INPUT1 / INPUT2

End Sub
```

Here is the image of the ouput i am getting for the addition operation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the code to force numeric operations.

```
ANSWER = Val(INPUT1) + Val(INPUT2)
```

You might want to put a check in there.

```
If IsNumeric(Input1) Then
  INPUT1 = Val(INPUT1)
Else
  INPUT1 = 0
End if
```

Something like that for each variable you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to look at here:

1. Anything typed into a text box is a string, such that `MsgBox TypeName(me.Textbox1)` will always gives:

   [image]
2. "`+`" will be a concatenation operator when both variables are strings.

Hence you will have to **explicitly** convert the variables into numbers before using the `+` to add them so that the `+` will not be treated as a concatenation operator.

To convert text to numbers, you can use `Val`, `CDbl`, `CInt`, `CLng` or `CSng`. Choose the best fit.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `-*\/` to convert the the text to number:

```
ANSWER = INPUT1 - 0 + INPUT2  
ANSWER = INPUT1 * 1 + INPUT2
ANSWER = INPUT1 / 1 + INPUT2
ANSWER = INPUT1 \ 1 + INPUT2  ' integer division
ANSWER = INPUT1 + --INPUT2
ANSWER = INPUT1 - -INPUT2
```